# ASP.NET Web API Date Serialization

Tags: extjs, extjs4, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API method that returns an object with a `BirthDate` Property.

In Fiddler, the web method json respose of the BirthDate is:

```
"BirthDate": "2006-08-04T00:00:00Z"
```

But in my ExtJS 4.2 DateField I have:

[image]

So I guess, the browser (Chrome) is substracting the TimeZone and thats why I dont see in the DateField 08/04/2006.

Any clue on how to solve this?

Comment: How are you returning the `BirthDate` property, as a `DateTime` or as a formatted `string`? You could try formatting the date portion of your `DateTime` in your code to a UTC string and return that. Then you won't have to worry about time or timezones.

Comment: I think it worked, I return the date from server as .ToUniversalTime (UTC) and now its working fine :) I guess. Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you want to answer it and I will chose it as the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you returning the `BirthDate` property, as a DateTime or as a formatted string? You could try formatting the date portion of your DateTime in your code to a UTC string and return that. Then you won't have to worry about time or timezones.